# Having problem with createBottomTabNavigator and Unrecognized font family using the latest react-native version

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, native-base, react-navigation-stack

[error image simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nukW.png)

I'm a newbie to react-native development and actually am following a tutorial video in cloning an Instagram application. But it seems the guy is using an older react-native version which is causing me a lot of error. I have tried all solutions and online but none is seems working.

For the Icons first:

Have tried using *npx react-native link* not working also configuring manually but none is working for me and it's giving me a tough time.

For the navigation:

Have even tried the sample from the official site but it's not actually working for me.

I wouldn't mind if I need revamp of the code from the start again because I have deleted and restarts the full project countless number of times.

Thank you in anticipation...

**This is my App.js**

```
/**
* Sample React Native App
* https://github.com/facebook/react-native
*
* @format
* @flow
*/

import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import MainScreen from './Components/MainScreen'

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   Main: {screen: MainScreen},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

**This is my MainScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import AddMediaTab from './AppTabNavigator/AddMediaTab'

import HomeTab from './AppTabNavigator/HomeTab'

import LikesTab from './AppTabNavigator/LikesTab'

import ProfileTab from './AppTabNavigator/ProfileTab'

import SearchTab from './AppTabNavigator/SearchTab'

import { Icon } from 'native-base'

//import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

class MainScreen extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft: <Icon name="ios-camera-outline" style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }} />,
    title: "Instagram",
    headerRight:<Icon style={{ paddingRight:10 }} name="ios-send-outline" />
}
render() {
    return (
        <AppTabNavigator />
    );
}
}

const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({

HomeTab: {
    screen: HomeTab
},
SearchTab: {
    screen: SearchTab
},
AddMediaTab: {
    screen: AddMediaTab
},
LikesTab: {
    screen: LikesTab
},
ProfileTab: {
    screen: ProfileTab
}
})

export default MainScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
    });
```

**This is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "InstagramClone",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.11",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to split your question into multiple relevant questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when a native module is not linked. With latest, React Native you shouldn't run `react-native link` at all. It's automatic.

After installing your dependencies, make sure to install pods:

```sh
cd ios && pod install
```

Then rebuild your app"

```sh
react-native run-ios // or run-android
```

Comment: I guess the first error is solved but the new error now is **`Unrecognized font family 'Ionicons'** Please help on that because am using Icon from native-base

Comment: According to the native-base documentation I just read, it's like it doesn't support react-native 16.0 upwards. But what is baffling me again, When I change the Icon name to "planet" i.e from <Icon name="ios-send-outline" /> to <Icon name="planet" /> it's only showing the planet icon on the android simulator but still not recognizing in iOS simulator